# Solving three equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was just wondering how would one solve three equations which are in a form like these. Tried substitution, elimination and everything but couldn't find out the solution.

The equations are :
$-2A+C=3$, $3A+B-2C=1$, $-A+C-B=-2$

Edit- Whenever I try to solve two equations, I arrive at an already provided third equation. Does that mean that these equations are true for more than one values of $A$, $B$ and $C$(they are arbitrary)?

Comment: If it happens so (did not check), and may happen, then yes, you have multiple solutions: all those that satisfy the equation that remains common.

Comment: checked, the equations are incompatible, so there is no solution. You cannot arrive at "an already provided equation", maybe the one you arrive has same coefficients of the unknown, but not the same RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitution and elimination will work as normal but you need to work with all three in each step.

**Using Substitution**

Rearrange first: $C=3+2A$

Sub into the other two: $3A+B-2(3+2A)=1$ and $-A+3+2A-B=-2$

Simplifies to: $-A+B=7$ and $A-B=-5$

Then rearrange the first of these: $B=7+A$

Sub int the other: $A-(7+A)=-5$

As $-7\neq-5$ then there is no solution.

**Reason for no solution**

As you know from solving two equations you get no solution if the two lines are parallel. Each of your equations represents a plane in 3D space. You have the special situation where the three planes do not intersect at a single point.

[image]

**Update:**

Just read your edit. If you arrived at the third equation using the first two then you made a mistake in your arithmetic. If I change the question slightly we can get that situation.

Modified equations: $−2A+C=3$, $3A+B−2C=\color{red}{-1}$, $−A+C−B=−2$

**Using Substitution**

Rearrange first: $C=3+2A$

Sub into the other two: $3A+B-2(3+2A)=-1$ and $-A+3+2A-B=-2$

Simplifies to: $-A+B=5$ and $A-B=-5$

Then rearrange the first of these: $B=5+A$

Sub int the other: $A-(5+A)=-5$

As $5=-5$ then there is an infinite number of solutions.

We could let $A=t, t\in\mathbb{R}$ and hence $B=5+t$ and hence $C=3+2t$

Graphically the three planes would be like this. Different values of $t$ represents different points long the line of intersection.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! That cleared it out. Crystal clear! I up voted and accepted your answer. Don't you think this post might be useful for others who have the same problem? Would you consider up voting this post?

Comment: @Ziatan I read your edit and added some more details. I also noticed I had a minor typo which I've corrected.

Comment: What about the upvote? Lol it's up to you

Comment: Lol well I was asking you to do it. But nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the augmented matrix:
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
-2&0&1&3\\3&1&-2&1\\-1&-1&1&-2
\end{array}\right]&\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&1&-1&2\\-2&0&1&3\\3&1&-2&1
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&1&-1&2\\0&2&-1&7\\0&-2&1&-5
\end{array}\right]\\&\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&1&-1&2\\0&2&-1&7\\0&0&0&2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
The rank of the augmented matrix is greater than the rank of the left-hand matrix, hence the system has no solution.

Comment: great answer. Can you suggest me any post on here or explain it by yourself or any webpage where rank of matrix is explained from the basic to the advanced level?

Comment: @Zlatan:  There are for suremany posts where this is explained, but I don't know very well the site. You can look at this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29). What's not said on this page is that the rank of a matrix is also the rank of the associated linear map, i.e.  the dimension of the image of this linear map (which explains why similar matrices have the same rank).